# What is an upper bound on formula size when converting 3-SAT to UNIQUE 3-SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, 3-sat

What is an upper bound on formula size when converting 3-SAT to UNIQUE 3-SAT?

We can use the [Valiant Vazirani Therom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valiant%E2%80%93Vazirani_theorem), also found [here (in more detail)](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST07/scribe/lect12.pdf).

Essentially, it is a randomized algorithm that converts a SAT formula into another SAT formula that has only 1 satisfying variable assignment (called UNIQUE-SAT) with high probability.

I'm wondering what the upper bounds are on the size of the formula.  The information I have proves that it is polynomial, but I hope we can get more specific.  Can anyone find a more exact upper bounds?

Comment: @Raphael:  I haven't tried much to be honest.  It seems to me that we start with a given formula, and can essentially transform it via an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m$ is a guess at $\log_2{\text{(size of new formula)}}$, and $n$ is the size of the original formula.  Thus we will have used a linear transformation from the old formula to a new formula.  So it seems to me that the new formula size is related to this $(m \times n)$, and thus the new formula size is $O(n \cdot n)$, since $m$ will not exceed $n$ in the worst case.